# Problems with .hover() on IE8+ and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, hover

I'm trying to make a plug-in using jQuery UI.

I want to hide/show the text on button after an hover of this button.

This plug-in working really well on FF working too on IE8+ and Chrome but with some problems.

Sometime, the even "mouseleave" not working when I get out of the button to quickly.

```
(function($) {
jQuery.fn.extend({
    buttonHover: function() {
        jQuery(this).hover(function() {
            jQuery(this).button({text: true});
        }, function() {
            jQuery(this).button({text: false});
        }).button({text: false});
    },
```

Someone knows why I have this problem? Can I fixe it?

EDIT :

Well I found a solution but it's not what I'm looking for, if jQuery UI have an update...

When I'm using this code :

```
        buttonHover: function() {
        jQuery(this).hover(function() {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("ui-button-icon-only").addClass("ui-button-text-icon-primary");
        }, function() {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("ui-button-text-icon-primary").addClass("ui-button-icon-only");
        }).removeClass("ui-button-text-icon-primary").addClass("ui-button-icon-only");
    }
```

It's working well on FF, Chrome and IE8+ but I'm still looking for a better solution

Comment: use "mouseover" event rather than of hover

Comment: I have the same problem when I'm using mouseenter/mouseout-leave

Comment: You realize you're creating a new button each time, to change options on an already existing button you'd do `$( ".selector" ).button( "option", "text", false );`

Comment: Yes I know but evenif I'm using the parameter "option" my problem is already here :/ Do you know if IE or Chrome have a time limit for the event .hover (mouseenter/mouseleave)?